# Change only Numbes in HTML option TAG

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to change the numbers in within the option tag with JS?

```
<select name="resunit">
    <option value="res_0">R1 (18768194)</option>
    <option value="res_1">R2 (44507354)</option>
    <option value="res_2">R3 (15217874)</option>
    <option value="unit_1">U1 (3047)</option>
    <option value="unit_2">U2 (10)</option>
    <option value="unit_3">U3 (60)</option>
</select>
```

e.g.

```
<option value="res_0">R1 (18768194)</option>
```

to

```
<option value="res_0">R1 (10)</option>
```

Comment: You'll need a regex and the replace function but we'll need some more information about the conditions.  Is it only R type that will be changed? How far do the R numbers go? Is the number always in parenthesis?

Comment: only the numer in parenthesis

Comment: What about the other questions?

Comment: e.g. `if($("select[name=resunit] option").val()=="res_0")` then change the number in () to 10 or `if($("select[name=resunit] option").val()=="res_1")` then change the number in () to 12

Comment: Does the code need to check the U options also?

Comment: no only the options value needs to be checked by if clause but this is not the problem

Comment: According to your code the Us are options also.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but have a look:

```
var select = document.getElementsByName("resunit")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    if (select[i].value === "res_0") {
        select[i].innerHTML = "R1 (10)";
    } else if (select[i].value === "res_1") {
        select[i].innerHTML = "R2 (12)";
    }
}
```